# Filter SQL Queries on XML attributes

Tags: sql, xml

I have a column `otar.Results` in my sql database containing xml data.
Here is an example of the xml data:

```
<certInformationList>
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="1" qxCertInformation="8;20021" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="2" qxCertInformation="" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="3" qxCertInformation="3308ASX1D1I1S1V4AAR5AE00910WA3WK1M5C1Q8P1W1" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="4" qxCertInformation="2014-04-29" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="5" qxCertInformation="13:07:43" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="6" qxCertInformation="" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="7" qxCertInformation="" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="8" qxCertInformation="" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="9" qxCertInformation="" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="10" qxCertInformation="9150077-263" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="11" qxCertInformation="260201" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="12" qxCertInformation="" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="13" qxCertInformation="" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="14" qxCertInformation="" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="15" qxCertInformation="" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="16" qxCertInformation="" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="17" qxCertInformation="" />
  <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="18" qxCertInformation="" />
</certInformationList>
```

I want to filter my query so I can get the records where `layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="1"`  and `qxCertInformation="8;20021`"

I've tried

```
otar.Results.exist('/certInformationList/certItem[layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="1" and qxCertInformation="8;20021"]') = 1
```

But it doesn't return any records.

Note: I have to be able to build the query dynamically

Any help would be very appreciated.

Best regards
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@` at the beginning of attribute name to reference attributes in XPath, otherwise it will be misunderstood as child element of the same name :

```
/certInformationList/certItem[@layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="1" and @qxCertInformation="8;20021"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a table with two records, one is as your example (shortend!), the second has got the "8;20021" changed. Only the first comes back in the select:

```
DECLARE @otar TABLE(id INT, Results XML);
INSERT INTO @otar VALUES
 (1,'<certInformationList>
        <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="1" qxCertInformation="8;20021" />
     </certInformationList>')
,(2,'<certInformationList>
        <certItem layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="1" qxCertInformation="8;20022" />
     </certInformationList>');

SELECT *
FROM @otar AS o
WHERE o.Results.exist('//certItem[@layoutSeqOrSealDescrID="1" and @qxCertInformation="8;20021"]')=1;
```

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the @ before layoutSeqOrSealDescrID and qxCertInformation